# Number of strongly-connected digraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Is there a closed formula for the number of non-isomorphic
>   strongly-connected digraphs on $n$ vertices?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the references [here](http://oeis.org/A035512)?

Comment: Yes, I read the paper of V. A. Liskovets. But I couldn't find there  any **closed** formula at all.